# pdf is not showing properly wordpress flipbook

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I use flipbook plugin for viewing pdfs beautifully, but have one problem pdf is working properly on some screens but there are screens that pdf is all gray but pages need to be in white also pages aren't loading properly.

Once I got that screen where pdf is not showing properly, in console log I saw that jquery isn't defined, then I added jquery to that page template and that error lost but still can't understand what's the problem that in my screen pdf is ok but in the other one not.

Comment: You should consult the plugin author instead.

Answer (score 0):

By "Screen" do you mean your device screen? If so then it might not be responsive or might not have cross browser support, although now a days this is a necessity. Many flipbook plugins also provide a flash option, try using that as flash is pretty compatible.

Comment: no I mean for desktop screens, because for example my screen is 1366x768 and all is ok but when I tested in other pc with same resolution pdf is not showing properly. This is strange

Comment: Are both browsers the same?